# Using iTextSharp, is there a way to keep text from staying in a rectangle

Tags: c#, itext

I have an existing PDF (not with form fields - more of a scanned document), and am using PdfReader to load the PDF "template" so that I write text on it.

For position simple fields I am using:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templatePath);


Chunk chunk = new Chunk(text, fontToUse);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.Add(chunk);

PdfContentByte canvas = this.PdfWriter.DirectContent;
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(this.PdfContentByte, alignment, phrase, left, top, 0);
```

I also need to write some text to a specific area which is a 400 x 200 rectangle. Since the size of the text varies, it may or may not fit into the rectangle.

Is there a way to write text to the rectangle, and if the text is too large for it to simply not appear (like overflow hidden would work in HTML)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

```
Phrase myText = new Phrase(text);

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

table.TotalWidth = 300;
table.LockedWidth = true;

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(myText);
cell.Border = 0;
cell.FixedHeight = 40;

table.AddCell(cell);
table.WriteSelectedRows
(
 0, 
 -1, 
 300,
 700,
 writer.DirectContent
);
```